# Yahoo YQL Authentication error

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

Yahoo put in a new UI for the YQL today and now I keep getting the following error message.  I've got this msg before, but by logging out and logging-in it would go away.  That doesn't do it anymore.

"Authentication Error.  The table requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least USER is expected"

Here is my YQL, it worked fine last week.

```
select * from fantasysports.teams.roster where league_key='371.l.150156';
```

Here is the new url for the [YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql)

Comment: Here is a user who experienced the same error a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153252/yql-api-request-private-data-authentication-error?rq=1  he also got no anwer

Comment: Here's another similar case...but using oauth and code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877486/issue-with-yahoo-sports-api?rq=1

Comment: Before somebody gives this an off topic, see this link (below) Yahoo is now directing the YQL community to come here for answers, its the only place I can go  https://developer.yahoo.com/support/yql/

Answer (score 0):

Its not just me Yahoo confirmed the console is down. Since 17 days ago.

"We are aware that the YQL Console is offline. We are investigating the issue."

source: https://twitter.com/ydn/status/936763870974173185

Comment: Another question with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578731/is-the-yql-console-page-down-for-everyone-again